# How to create a bash file that calls itself multiple times?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a linux machine.
I need to create a bash file that calls itself multiple times and when a certain condition met, do some actions and exit.

For this i should execute the file itself with a param, for example:

```
./mybash -t 50
```

-t stand for the times i want this file to call itself and when the if statement is true then: print, wait and exit.

So to create the bash i wrote the following (Which is not currently working)

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts t: option
do
case "${option}"
in
t) TIMES=${OPTARG};;
esac
done


echo "this is the run number: $TIMES"

if [ $TIMES = 0 ]; then
    #psudo here
    echo "Hello"
    wait 5 seconds
    echo "Done"
else
    sh ./myBash.bash -t ($TIMES - 1)
fi
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are expecting `-t` option in script but passing `-n`.
- You need to use `$((...))` for shell arithmetic.
- Suggest you to use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` in `bash`.
- Use `wait` instead of `sleep`

You may use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts t: option
do
   case "${option}" in
   t) TIMES=${OPTARG};;
   esac
done


echo "this is the run number: $TIMES"

if [[ $TIMES -eq 0 ]]; then
    #psudo here
    echo "Hello"
    sleep .1
    echo "Done"
else
    bash "$0" -t $((TIMES - 1))
fi
```

You may then invoke your script as:

```
bash myBash.bash -t 5
```